# why is the result of my operation is diffrent with my calculator in java

Tags: java

i m setting my value of my variable, and i get some problem in the result of my operation. im using modulo and it make my result of the aritmatic is different with my calculator

this is for java language

```
out.println("11^"+ (16)+" = "+Math.pow(11, 16)+" mod "+17+" = "+(Math.pow(11, 16))%17);
```

i expect the output of (Math.pow(11, 16))%17) to be 1, but the actual output is 0.0

Comment: use BigInteger as this is much too big to fit in Int

Comment: @LalitVerma `Math.pow` returns a double, shouldn't be a problem

Comment: `%` always return remainder value which is `0.0` in your case.

Comment: Well ... `System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(11).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(16), BigInteger.valueOf(17)))` would give you the expected `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
    new BigDecimal(11).pow(16).remainder(new BigDecimal(17));
```

Answer (score -1):

Because 11^16 is truncated to fit in a double value.

UPDATE: Tip: It would fit in a long though